# Flutter uni_links (deep linking) does not work on iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, deep-linking

I am trying to get deep linking working with my application.
I am using uni_links https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links

I followed the instruction on the page and got the deep linking working for Android device.

But I don't seems to be able to get the deep linking working on iPhone simulator .

```
<?xml ...>
<!-- ... other tags -->
<plist>
<dict>
  <!-- ... other tags -->
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
      <string>Editor</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
      <string>www.bbb.com</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>https</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
  <!-- ... other tags -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

On the android simulator when i click links like https://www.bbb.com/register/xxxx
it open the app.

But on iPhone simulator it just goes to the website.

In the code I am using

```
UniLinksType _type = UniLinksType.string;
```

Option.

Do I have to install the app on a real device to get it to work?

Can anyone provide any suggestion what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can anyone provide some assistance on this issue?